# Issue in updating scraped data to the already existing csv using beautiful soup

Tags: csv, python-2.7, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to update scraped data from a webpage to a already existing csv, which I generated when I ran the scraping code for 1st time. 
I want the new data to get appended below already scraped rows.

Below is the code I am using to scrape data and write csv:

```
import csv
import urllib2
import sys
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import islice
page = urllib2.urlopen('http://shop.ee.co.uk/mobile-phones/pay-monthly/').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
soup.prettify()
with open('EE_AppendTesting.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    #spamwriter.writerow(["Date","Month","Day of Week","Device Name","Price","Plan Monthly Price"])    
    items = soup.findAll('h2', {"class":"heading2 no-margin-top"})
    prices = soup.findAll('span', {"class": "price"})
    monthly = soup.findAll('div',{"class":"mrc-holder"})
    for item, price, monthly1 in zip(items, prices, monthly):
        textcontent = u' '.join(islice(monthly1.stripped_strings, 2, 3, 1))
        if textcontent:
            spamwriter.writerow([time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),time.strftime("%B"),time.strftime("%A") ,unicode(item.string).encode('utf8').strip(),unicode(price.string).encode('utf8').replace('Â£','£').strip(),unicode(textcontent).encode('utf8').replace('Â£','£').strip()])
```

Right now, each time I run the code, new data gets appended **with empty rows** between each data entry. Below is the sample of appended csv:

```
26-12-2012  December    Wednesday   Nokia Lumia 920 White   £ 19.99 £46.00
26-12-2012  December    Wednesday   iPhone 5 64GB Black £ 139.99    £56.00

26-12-2012  December    Wednesday   Nokia Lumia 820 FREE    £36.00

26-12-2012  December    Wednesday   iPhone 5 16GB White £ 19.99 £56.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used " lineterminator='\n' " method in code to solve the above mentioned problem.
Updated code will look like:

```
with open('EE_AppendTesting.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',lineterminator='\n')
```

Comment: Or csv can be opened in 'ab' mode instead of 'a', No need to use lineterminator method in that case.